# Recording setup for live performances with various sound engineers in various venues

Tags: recording, performing, equipment

My band plays in a variety of venues with a variety of sound engineers with varying levels of competence. The venues supply the mics and DIs.

So we would like to record live the raw feeds from the mics and DIs on separate channels before they go to the sound board so that we can edit and mix them later.

What kinds of equipment should we be looking for to do this with a minimal amount of fuss onstage?  There's just the band members, no budget for a separate recording engineer.

Comment: Sorry, equipment searches are off-topic here. If you want to record each instrument directly and then send a copy to the engineer, you're going to spend a lot of money and have a very long setup time. A better option is to get a portable stereo recorder with built in microphones and just record what the audience hears. That will also help you assess how good the engineers you work with are.

Comment: @ToddWilcox our close reason states "Questions seeking recommendations for specific equipment are off-topic, because they are primarily opinion based. Instead, **describe the required function and setting in which the equipment will be used, and ask what you should look for to achieve that.**" Surely that's *exactly* what the poster has done here - described what's wanted, and then asked what kind of thing would be appropriate?

Comment: @topomorto You raise an excellent point. I read the question as asking for the names of specific products but now I see how the actual intention is more general and on topic. I might even answer it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done live recording like what you are describing. We use a "splitter Snake" which sends two outputs for each input, one going to house sound, one going to recording setup.

You could achieve the same thing with mic splitter boxes on each mic, since the house sound will likely already be set up.  You will also need dual output DI boxes for your DI's. Extra mic and instrument cables for each also.

You will need a recording setup that has enough inputs for your DIs and mics. A Digital Interface and a Laptop should be enough to get the basic tracks down. There will be some extra setup time as you plug in the connections and check the levels on your system, but if the band practices before hand and everyone has their job set, it shouldn't add too much more time to your regular stage setup.